# Sending a string with Ajax to controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, spring-boot

My knowledge of Spring boot is very low.
I have made a table in HTML, which when I click on, an event is sent to a Javascript function, in which I try to catch the Id (a string) of the cell and send it to the controller. I tried many examples from internet but none worked for me, can anyone help me please? 
The id is being caught correctly by mouse click, but I have a problem with sending.

This is my JSP

```
<c:forEach items= "${rooms2}" var="m" >
<tr>
<td style="background-color:OldLace">${m.day }</td>
    <c:choose>
    <c:when test="${m.hour1confirm==false}">
    <td style="background-color:green" id="${m.hour1}"  onclick=
    "content(this)" >${m.hour1 }</td>
...
<script >
//  <script type="text/javascript">

function content(elem)
{
//  $(document).ready(function() 
//  {
//     // PREPARE FORM DATA
//          var idt =elem.id;
//          console.log(idt);
//          // DO POST
//          $.post({
//              type : "POST",
//              url :"reservation2",
//              // contentType: "application/json",
//              data : JSON.stringify(idt),
//              dataType : 'json',
//                  })

//  });

         var idt =elem.id;
         console.log(idt);
         $.ajax({

             url:"reservation2",
                    type: 'POST',
                    data:  idt,             
                    dataType: "text",          
                    contentType: false,
                    mimeType: false,
                    success: function(response){ 
                        console.log(data);              
                        return false;     
                    } 
                });

}

</script>
```

this is controller

```
.
.
.
//    @RequestMapping(value = "/reservation2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
//    public String reservation2(@ModelAttribute("idt") String idt , Model model) {
//        return "Reservation2";}



   @RequestMapping(value = "/reservation2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody
    String Submit(@RequestParam("idt") String idt) {
        // your logic here
        return "reservation2";
    }


    @RequestMapping(value = "/reservation2", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String reservation(Model model) {  
   List<Room> rooms2= new ArrayList<>();
   System.out.println(rooms2);      
   rooms2= x.findAll();
   model.addAttribute("rooms2", rooms2);   
   return "reservation2";
...
```

when I run I get this error in console :

```
POST http://localhost:8080/reservation2 403 ()
```

Comment: What is printing console.log(idt);

Comment: 11               
                                                                                                         
       VM4889:1 POST http://localhost:8080/reservation2 403 ()                                 11 is the idt string which is catched by click

Comment: As asked by @JPRLCol, what does console.log(idt) in the JS function prints?

Comment: Do you get any error on spring? 403 error seems to be a problem with your csrf configuration (on spring).

Comment: No,I don't get any errors on Spring

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your request to something like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: "/reservation2", //added '/' in the beginning
  type: 'POST',
  data: idt,
  dataType: "text",
  contentType: "text/plain", //change
  //mimeType: false,   //remove
  success: function(response) {
    console.log(data);
    return false;
  }
});
```

and your controller to this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reservation2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String reservation2(@RequestBody String idt) 
{
    // your logic here
    return "reservation2";
}
```

Comment: No change again . Also ,instead of   '@RequestParam'  ,I tried  '@ModelAttribute'

Comment: It is same;no change

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are not sending the right parameter along the way. When you do the ajax post request, in the field data can you specify the name of the parameter you are sending?

Can you try this one

```
$.ajax({

         url:"reservation2",
                type: 'POST',
                data:  {"idt": idt},             
                dataType: "json",          
                contentType: "application/json",
                success: function(response){ 
                    console.log(data);              
                    return false;     
                } 
            });
```